# Как разместить иконку справа от названия строки в шапке таблицы

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Делаю так

```
<thead id="backgroundSearchHead">

    <tr>
       <th colspan="4">Розпорядчий документ</th>                      
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th>Код<span class="fa fa-fw fa-sort pull-right"></span></th>
        <th>Номер<span class="fa fa-fw fa-sort pull-right"></span></th>
        <th>Дата<span class="fa fa-fw fa-sort pull-right"></span></th>
        <th>Шифр<span class="fa fa-fw fa-sort pull-right"></span></th>

    </tr>

</thead>
```

В итоге получается так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы иконка была справа от названия?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например повесить иконку на `absolute`:

```css
th {
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 20px !important;
}

th>.fa{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  right: 5px;
  top:50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<table class="table">
   <thead id="backgroundSearchHead">

     <tr>
       <th colspan="4">Розпорядчий документ</th>                      
     </tr>

     <tr>
       <th>Код<span class="fa fa-fw fa-sort pull-right"></span></th>
       <th>Номер<span class="fa fa-fw fa-sort pull-right"></span></th>
       <th>Дата<span class="fa fa-fw fa-sort pull-right"></span></th>
       <th>Шифр<span class="fa fa-fw fa-sort pull-right"></span></th>

     </tr>

  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">Lorem ipsum.</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Для bootstrap 4 на флексах:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<table class="table">
   <thead id="backgroundSearchHead">

     <tr>
       <th colspan="4">Розпорядчий документ</th>                      
     </tr>

     <tr>
       <th>
         <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center flex-nowrap">
           Код<span class="fa fa-fw fa-sort pull-right"></span>
         </div>
       </th>
       <th>
         <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center flex-nowrap">
           Номер<span class="fa fa-fw fa-sort pull-right"></span>
         </div>
       </th>
       <th>
         <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center flex-nowrap">
           Дата<span class="fa fa-fw fa-sort pull-right"></span>
         </div>
       </th>
       <th>
         <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center flex-nowrap">
           Шифр<span class="fa fa-fw fa-sort pull-right"></span>
         </div>
       </th>

     </tr>

  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="4">Lorem ipsum.</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Использую 3 версию, сделал как вы сказали, иконка находит на название строки

Comment: @СергейНиконенко, подправила, но вообще если Вы до такой степени сжимаете таблицу, логичнее сделать ее адаптивной или уменьшать шрифт для моб. разрешений

Comment: агась, увидел, спасибо большое, не я не сжимаю таблицу, это просто часть таблицы, так там шапка в три раза больше)